# How does double Riemann sum actually work?

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum, multiple-integral

I'm in an advanced calculus class and studying double integral. My question is about how double Riemann sum actually work as algebraic steps? I mean I understand essentially it is summing up the volumes of small rectangles and I can make sense from it by thinking it as a 2D-array with 2 counters one of which is for row and another one is for column for indexing the correct base 2D-rectangles. But I get confused each time I try to view it as 2 nested plain summations, that I'm not sure which entity is the summand of which summation. I got that the $f(x_{ij},y_{ij}) \triangle A$ is the summand of the inner summation/sigma, but I started to confuse when I tried to think the result from the inner summation as the summand of the outer summation. This is the expression in my textbook that I'm talking about: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m} f(x_{ij},y_{ij}) \triangle A$. Thanks!!

Comment: It could help you to consider small values of $m,n$. For instance, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^2\sum\limits_{j=1}^2f(x_{i,j},y_{i,j})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^2\big(f(x_{i,1},y_{i,1})+f(x_{i,2},y_{i,2})\big)=f(x_{1,1},y_{1,1})+f(x_{2,1},y_{2,1})+f(x_{1,2},y_{1,2})+f(x_{2,2},y_{2,2})$.

Comment: So it doesn't work as the result of the inner summation being used as the summand of the outer summation?

Comment: The double summation consists of two sums whose indices ($i$ and $j$) operate independently of one another. What I did was to first sum over one index, $j$, which generates the two terms in the $i$-dependent summand. Then summing over $i$, we get two terms for each value of $i$. But I could just as easily compute the sum over all $i$ first, then over $j$. Either direction is fine in this case. For the purpose of demonstration, I thought it would be helpful expand the sum from inside-out.

Comment: @user170231 Thanks I think I'm getting it now: the summand of the outer summation is the rectangle of the i-th row.